# SELinux blocking execution in systemd unit

Tags: fedora, systemd, selinux

I use Fedora 31 and tried to set up a Teamspeak server. When I look in `journalctl -u teamspeak` I get the following error:

```
mar 09 22:22:46 melchior systemd[1]: Started Teamspeak server.
mar 09 22:22:46 melchior systemd[20187]: teamspeak.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
mar 09 22:22:46 melchior systemd[20187]: teamspeak.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /srv/teamspeak/3.11.0/ts3server: Permission denied
mar 09 22:22:46 melchior systemd[1]: teamspeak.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
mar 09 22:22:46 melchior systemd[1]: teamspeak.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My systemd unit looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Teamspeak server
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=teamspeak
Group=teamspeak
WorkingDirectory=/srv/teamspeak/data/
ExecStart=/srv/teamspeak/versions/3.11.0/ts3server dbsqlpath=/srv/teamspeak/versions/3.11.0/sql/ serverquerydocs_path=/srv/teamspeak/versions/3.11.0/serverquerydocs/ license_accepted=1 default_voice_port=9987 filetransfer_port=30033 query_port=10011
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I use the following ansible playbook to set it up:

```
- name: create teamspeak server base folder
  file:
    path: "/srv/teamspeak"
    state: directory
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0755
- name: create teamspeak user
  user:
    name: teamspeak
    comment: "Teamspeak 3 server user"
    system: true
    create_home: false
    shell: /sbin/nologin
    # NOTE: SELinux blocks systemd from starting any binary in a user's home
    #       folder which is why we need versions/ and data/
    home: /srv/teamspeak/data
- name: create teamspeak server user folder
  file:
    path: "/srv/teamspeak/data"
    state: directory
    owner: teamspeak
    group: teamspeak
    mode: 0755
- name: create teamspeak server version folder
  file:
    path: "/srv/teamspeak/versions/{{ teamspeak_version }}"
    state: directory
- name: download teamspeak server
  get_url:
    url: "https://files.teamspeak-services.com/releases/server/{{ teamspeak_version }}/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-{{ teamspeak_version }}.tar.bz2"
    dest: "/srv/teamspeak/versions/{{ teamspeak_version }}/server.tar.bz2"
    checksum: "sha256:18c63ed4a3dc7422e677cbbc335e8cbcbb27acd569e9f2e1ce86e09642c81aa2"
  register: tarball
- name: unpack teamspeak3 server files
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ tarball.dest }}"
    dest: "/srv/teamspeak/versions/{{ teamspeak_version }}/"
    remote_src: true
    extra_opts:
      - "--strip-components=1"
      # Prevent files from being world writable like some are in the tarball
      - "--no-same-permissions"
    creates: "/srv/teamspeak/versions/{{ teamspeak_version }}/ts3server"
- name: install service file
  template:
    src: teamspeak.service
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/teamspeak.service
  register: service
- name: reload systemd units
  when: service.changed
  command: systemctl daemon-reload
- name: "enable teamspeak service"
  systemd:
    name: teamspeak
    enabled: true
    state: started
```

Looking in `sealert -l "*"` shows:

```
SELinux is preventing (s3server) from execute access on the file ts3server.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that (s3server) should be allowed execute access on the ts3server file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c '(s3server)' --raw | audit2allow -M my-s3server
# semodule -X 300 -i my-s3server.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:init_t:s0
Target Context                unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0
Target Objects                ts3server [ file ]
Source                        (s3server)
Source Path                   (s3server)
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          melchior
Source RPM Packages           
Target RPM Packages           
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.14.4-45.fc31.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     melchior
Platform                      Linux melchior 5.4.17-200.fc31.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat
                              Feb 1 19:00:13 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   65
First Seen                    2020-03-09 22:22:45 CET
Last Seen                     2020-03-10 20:07:00 CET
Local ID                      20f823c0-8e46-46d1-a51c-659040857b34

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1583867220.254:4234): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=11418 comm="(s3server)" name="ts3server" dev="dm-0" ino=1032133 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0


Hash: (s3server),init_t,var_t,file,execute
```

I can run the server without issue if I just do `sudo -u teamspeak /srv/teamspeak/versions/3.11.0/ts3server dbsqlpath=/srv/teamspeak/versions/3.11.0/sql/ serverquerydocs_path=/srv/teamspeak/versions/3.11.0/serverquerydocs/ license_accepted=1 default_voice_port=9987 filetransfer_port=30033 query_port=10011`

I have no idea how to debug this further. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out SELinux has an idea that binaries can only be executed from certain locations and my custom directory was not explicitly marked as allowed. It inherited the type `var_t` from `/srv/.*` (I think).

To get an extensive list of current rules for all directories you can run `semanage fcontext --list`.

I added an exception using the following Ansible tasks:

```yaml
- name: set SELinux permissions on ts3server binaries
  sefcontext:
    target: "/srv/teamspeak/versions/[^/]+/ts3server"
    setype: bin_t
- name: reload SELinux policy to ensure that ts3server is executable
  command: restorecon -irv /srv/teamspeak/
  when: tarball.changed
```

The same can be achieved by using the `semanage fcontext` command followed by `restorecon -irv /srv/teamspeak/`.

Answer (score 7):

We were facing similar problem when we wanted to start celery from systemd.

By following below steps it solved the problem:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t '/home/\<logged in user\>/.local/bin.*' 
sudo chcon -Rv -u system_u -t bin_t '/home/\<logged in user\>/.local/bin' 
sudo restorecon -R -v /home/\<logged in user\>/.local/bin 
sudo systemctl restart cele123
```

Celery executable was present in `/home/\<logged in user\>/.local/bin` directory. The same path was mentioned in `cele123.service` file in systemd folder.

Comment: It would be better to use a systemd user service instead of a system service here, when the service is confined to a user's home directory. If a system service, it should not be in any user's home directory.

Comment: thanks for the chcon command, it was exactly what i needed to get my systemd service working